# Want to store TestNg Report in separate folder with time stamping

Tags: report, testng

I want to store my reports in  another folder other than tests-output with time stamping
so i added a program:

```java
public class Customreporter implements IReporter
{   
    File fd = new File("");

    String date;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss");
    String folderNameWithTimeStamp = df.format(new Date());
    String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//Reports//";
    String finalPath = currentDir + folderNameWithTimeStamp;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) 
    {
        TestNG.getDefault().setOutputDirectory(finalPath);
        TestNG.getDefault().setXmlSuites(xmlSuites);
    }
}
```

and changed my xml to

```xml
<suite name="suitedemo" parallel="false">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.validation.Customreporter">
    </listeners>
    <test name="suitetestdemo">
        <suite-files>
            <suite-file path="./exceptions.xml" />
            <suite-file path="./screenshot.xml" />
        </suite-files>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Now it's creating a new folder every time, but it is storing sometimes only emailalablereport. What can I do, I dont want to customise reports I only want to store reports in new folder every time I run the suites. I changed the build file, it's working but we are executing xml files, not build.

Thanks in advance
Smith

Comment: Your description at the end is a bit unclear, could you try re-wording it?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar behaviour when using setOutputDirectory(). But when i changed the implementation it worked for me. Instead of creating a testng xml during design time, i create one dynamically using the TestNG XmlSuite class. And then setting a different output directory using setOutputDirectory(). Let me know if you need more help on this.

At a high level,

```
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setSuiteFiles(files);
List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
suites.add(suite);
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
```

I haven't tested the setSuiteFiles() as i have my testng xml at class level. Also this need not be a listener. You can have this in a main() or your init .......